# PyQt4 running external .py file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am making a GUI using PyQt4 and want it to call another python file upon a button being pushed.

This is form the GUI file: gui.py

```
# record push button
self.pbRec = QtGui.QPushButton("Record", self)
self.pbRec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 210, 113, 32))
self.pbRec.clicked.connect(self.recordSetUp)

def recordSetUp(self):
    self.genericThread = GenericThread(self.record)
    self.genericThread.start()
    # disable button after click
    self.pbRec.setEnabled(False)

def record(self):
    print 'initiating record.py'
    currentPath = os.curdir
    filePath = currentPath + '/lib/record.py'
    os.system('python ' + filePath)
    print 'record.py finished'
    # re enable button
    self.pbRec.setEnabled(True)
```

What record.py does is capture images from an external attached camera device until the user presses enter.

The following is how record.py ends

```
# Keep this process running until Enter is pressed
print "Press Enter to quit..."
try:
    sys.stdin.readline()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    controller.removeDevice(device)
```

It all works fine, when I press the record push button it loads up record.py and I press enter in terminal for it to finish.

But I can't press enter from my GUI to make record.py stop.

Is there a way to do this ? so that when I invoke an external file from my gui I can interact with it from the gui instead of terminal ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) and its `waitForFinished` method?

Comment: I think that will be easier than using a thread, but it will not solve the issue of having to press enter in terminal instead of from the gui to end record.py (from my understanding of it)

Comment: Your `os.system(...)` call launches a sub-process, but you have no control over it. If you use `QProcess`, you should have better control and the parent should wait/block until the child process exits/returns if you use the method above. I guess the parent can also listen for the `finished` signal asynchronously if you don't want it to block/wait. I'm not sure it matters how the user chooses to exit the child process (e.g. press enter on terminal, click exit button in GUI, etc)

Comment: @David. The external process is waiting for input from stdin. So start it with `QProcess`, and then do `process.write(b'\n')`.